# Ordering Django models by a method in the model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

So, say I have models like this:

```
class Foo(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=200)
    def latest_comment(self):
        try:
            object = self.comment_set.latest()
            if object:
                return object.when_posted.date()
        except:
            return ""

class Comment(Model):
   when_posted = DateTimeField()
   text = TextField()
```

Then this is the modelAdmin:

```
class FooAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'latest_comment']
    ordering = ['latest_comment']

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

It throws an error when I go to the admin site saying that 'latest_comment' was not found in app.Foo. Having it in list_display works fine. So, my question is: Is there a way to order models in list_display by methods of the model? And if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested the code, but just as an idea to try to implement this with overriding the queryset of the ModelAdmin with a annotate function to sort over a field from related field:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(FooAdmin, self).queryset(request)

        return qs.distinct() \
        .annotate(date_of_last_comment=Max('comment__date')) \
        .order_by('-date_of_last_comment')
```

Comment: This works great, just one problem. There is no way to go back to that ordering once it's been changed (to a name, if there was a field for that). But thanks, this should do for a while at least.

Answer (score 1):

Ordering is a SQL-level functionality and your database doesn't know anything about the methods on your model.

However, you can re-sort after the fact by converting your queryset to a list and then using something like `sorted`. See: http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

For what it's worth though, I doubt the sorted list will work in the admin. I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure Django needs it to stay a queryset.

Answer (score 0):

From [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_ordering), you could maybe define your own `get_ordering` method.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. `get_ordering` only allows you to dynamically specify the ordering; you *still* must use actual DB fields though, not a method on the model.

Comment: Good remark, indeed it does not allow you to customize the order.